# how to copy over the resource file in automated build, which are moved out of the web application project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I have separated my resource file to another class library and i am using expression builder to find the resource files.

I am doing an automated build, in that i am getting some error :

[exec] /temp/UserControls/Login.ascx(30): error ASPPARSE: The resource object with key 'Not_a_validUser' was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your automated build process make sure your resourcer project gets built first or at least before the web project does. Basically the compiler can not find this key "Not_a_validUser"  in your resources project which would imply the resources project has not been built yet with the latest changes.

Hope this helps!